# Google Play - update an unpublished app for existing users but not new users?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, updates

I have an unpublished app on Google Play which I want to update for my existing users, but not let new users download it.

The Google Play documentation seems to be saying that this can be done by simply uploading an updated apk (and not re-publishing the app):

> Unpublished Apps
>
> Existing app users will still be able to receive app updates, even if you unpublish your app. If you don't want new users to find and download your app but still want to provide updates to your existing users, set your app to Unpublished in the Developer Console.
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

But it seems unintuitive that an "unpublished" application would work that way. If the documentation is correct, how does Google Play tell the difference between an 'existing' user and a 'new' user?

Comment: I see a similar case with **Swiftkey Tablet** which is mantained only for update previous owners. They only have a message to **not buy the app** I don't know is there any other way.

Comment: If an app is unpublished it will not have a store listing and cannot be downloaded from the Play store. Everyone who already has it on their device is an "existing" user. There can be no "new" users unless you distribute your app via a different marketplace.

Comment: ok, i was a user, but because of a mistake i accidentally deleted the app from the device, or i bought a new device and i want to install the app on it. so, am i an existing user or not?

Comment: @csbg you are still an existing user as long as you are using the same Google account, and as long as you have not deleted the app from your Library.  Deleting the app from your Library does not happen when you delete it from the device, you have to do it as a separate step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a follow up: pushing an update to the unpublished app does make the update available to existing users only, but the app does not update automatically for these users. They must browse to the app page, where the app will have an "Update" button which can be triggered manually.

Comment: Do you have a source? I've asked Google Play Developer Support and they said this isn't the case: _"even though the app is in unpublished state the users will still be able to receive the update but their devices need to be set to auto-update in order to receive it automatically."_

Answer (score 1):

(This is just speculation, I'm not affiliated with Google in any way or anything)

The existing user probably has the app associated with the Google account they use to log in to the Play store.

If you look at your own profile in the store, there's a list of all the apps you've ever installed. I'm guessing the update would be available only for people who have your app in their lists, and the app will still be invisible for new users.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a user that has the app installed wants to update it, he requests an update of the app, it's different from re-installing the app as data from the app (a save from a game, or some saved preferences etc) are kept untouched, google play can easily detect that since it can detect what apps you have installed.