# Cancel support for legacy Android SDK level for new installs

Tags: android, google-play

My app currently has a `minSdkVersion` of 15 (ICS 4.0.3).
Due to additional dependencies, I have to go up with the min SDK to 19 (Kitkat 4.4).

I already build multiple APKs for min15 and min19 productFlavors.

I'd like to provide bugfixes for my existing users of min15, but don't want new users to install min15.

How can I accomplish this?

**Is it possible to unpublish the min15 for new installs, but still provide updates for existing users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. You can't unpublish single APKs, just the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

You should publish multiple apks for your app. one with `minSDK` 15 and another one with `minSDK` 19. Play-store allows this

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

Check docs [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks)

Comment: Thanks. The point is: I don't want new users to install the minSDK 15 app. It should only be possible for existing users to update bugfixed versions. So I don't know how this answer could help me.

Comment: I found this old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21308666/5993410) that says if you unpublished the apk, exiting users will still receive your new updates but however new users will not see this apk. So I guess you should create  the new apk (with minSdk 19) and unpublish the old one

Comment: Also check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60198/application-unpublished-from-google-play-store-but-user-still-can-add-their-revi)